# box-shadow + transition glitchiness in IE10

Tags: css-transitions, css, internet-explorer-10

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhdGZ/)

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="body">Blah blah blah</div>
</div>
```

```
#box {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px black;
}
#body {
    height:100px;
    transition: height 0.8s ease;
}
#body:hover {
    height: 200px;
}
```

In IE10, the shadow at the bottom of the box is glitchy when the transition changes the height of the content. Note that this only happens if it's the *content* box that changes height. If it's the *container*, the shadow works fine. However, I can't change the container's size since I want it to be dynamic to fits its contents.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rendering issue has been fixed in IE11. No need to worry!

Answer (score 3):

Best bet is to do the following. My guess is that because box-shadow is not applied to the element that's actually resizing that it can't resize with the contents. I'll need to do some more research, but this works:

## Edit for Fixed Container:

Apply a transparent box-shadow to each child.

### CSS:

```
<style type='text/css'>
    .box {
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px black;
    }
    .box .body {
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px transparent; 
    }
    .body {
        height:100px;
        transition: height 0.8s ease;

    }
    .body:hover {
        height: 200px;
    }
</style>
```

### HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="body">Blah blah blah</div>
    <div class="body">Blah blah blah 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's okay, but what if I have more than just one box in there?

Comment: You mean more than one div inside #box? Changed #body and #body:hover to .body and .body:hover. Then you can place as many boxes as you like (with class="body").

Comment: Yes, but then the shadow will be around each individual box, not the whole thing.

Comment: So let me make sure I understood this right: You added a *transparent* shadow on the `.body` elements? And somehow that fixes it... I'll go test that on my actual page... Unfortunately it still doesn't solve the problem. I've [edited the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhdGZ/1/) to make it a bit more like what I have on the live page, and the glitchiness is showing up again.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I've given you a +1, but the issue is now gone.